# Read from an exe using known data

Tags: visual-c++, exe

I want to read the code, more like variable and function names since I can catch values with CheatEngine, of an exe file. I got information about the file from Exeinfo PE which told me

> "Microsoft Visual C++ ver. 8.0 / Visual Studio 2005 [ Debug:02 ]"

[a screencap from Exeinfo PE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV4OD.png)
I have identified the code in assembly in some ways using IDA, radare2 and CheatEngine's Memory Table.
I don't know what else I can list so ask me if you need further details. thank you very much.

Comment: there're no names in .exe

Comment: but there are names in ms visual c++, right?

Comment: it doesn't go to .exe . This is debug build so some stuff may present

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is:

> How to view the function and variable names of a compiled program?

When compiled in debug mode, some information will be present in the binary.  If there is a .pdb it will contain additional debug information as well.

But when compiled in release mode, C++ itself does not compile in a way in which it retains any variable names or function names or other identifying information such as this.

The only exception to this is [RTTI or Run Time Type Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information).  RTTI you can think of like symbol names for virtual functions.  Microsoft Visual C++ predominantly does this but other compilers can as well.  RTTI can be parsed and it will give you the class names in relation to the their virtual function tables.  If the class does not have virtual functions, you will not find RTTI for it.

The best tool I know of for parsing RTTI is [Class Informer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/classinformer/) which is a plugin for IDA Pro.